Is it true that finite expectation leads to finite entropy?
Let $X$ be a random variable supported by the naturals, with a finite expectation. Show that $H(x)<\infty$. Also, give an example of a random variable supported by the naturals that has $H(x)=\infty$
Any idea how to go about this? I tried playing with the definitions and convergence test, but I'm not sure it's formal enough.

This post answers the second question: exhibit a discrete distribution with infinite entropy.
The idea is that high entropy is achieved with uniform distributions.  We therefore construct a distribution that for an extremely long time (that is, range of natural numbers) is uniform, and then for a much longer time is uniform with smaller probabilities, and so on.  With some care we can bound the sum of the probabilities (to ensure we get a valid distribution) and yet get the entropy to diverge.

As a shorthand, let $f(n) = 2^{2^n}.$  Let $X$ be the set of ordered pairs $(n,i)$ of integers where $1 \le n$ and $1 \le i \le f(n).$  Because $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ it is countable, whence there exists an enumeration $X = \{(n_1,i_1), (n_2,i_2), (n_3,i_3),\ldots\}.$  Let the distribution on $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ be given by the probabilities
$$p_j = \frac{2^{-n_j}}{f(n_j)}.$$
Because the entropy is a sum of non-negative terms, it converges absolutely, whence any re-arrangement of the sum converges to the same value.  Thus we may compute the entropy by adding the contributions for $n=1,$ $n=2,$ and so on.
The contribution for any such $n$ consists of $f(n)$ probabilities, each equal to $2^{-n}/f(n).$  Their total contribution to the cumulative probability is
$$P_n = f(n) \times 2^{-n}/f(n) = 2^{-n}$$
while their contribution to the entropy is
$$H_n = -f(n)\left[\frac{2^{-n}}{f(n)} \log_2\left(\frac{2^{-n}}{f(n)}\right)\right] = 2^{-n} (2^n + n) = 1+2^{-n}.$$
We see the sum of the $P_n$ is unity, showing that $(p_j)$ does give a valid probability distribution, but the entropy diverges to infinity because
$$H = -\sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j\log_2(p_j) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  H_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1+2^{-n} \gt \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1\to \infty.$$
There isn't much special about this particular function $f$ I proposed: the key is that the sum of $2^{-n}\log f(n)$ must diverge.
